# DELETE /_search/scroll api doesnt work with scroll_id in body

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using scroll for search and i have to clear the scroll_ids after search is done. I am using Nest and the api call looks like
[image] But i am  am getting this error back.

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
                "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: no scroll ids specified;"
            }
        ],
        "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
        "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: no scroll ids specified;"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

I am however able to do the same api call with the scroll_id as a parameter and it works fine.
I am using the 7.9 version of ES server and i am assuming this is getting retired and scroll_id's in the request body is what should be the right way of doing it according to the documentation.
Can anyone shade some light on why this is not working? Also, is there away to make doing the delete with the scroll_id in parameter using Nest?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that Postman is not sending the request body with the `DELETE` request? Do you get the same error when calling the clear scroll API with the client? Do you have a proxy in front of Elasticsearch that ignores the request body for `DELETE` requests?

Comment: yes, i have noticed it first time in Fiddler while running my .Net app. And what the NEST client produces is what you see in my postman test. But there is a proxy on our ES server. I will have to check that.

Comment: it turns out the proxy we have infront of ES is the culprit here. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that in your body `scroll_id` is sent as an array of string and it should be sent as a **simple string** instead:

```
DELETE /_search/scroll
{
  "scroll_id" : "DXF1ZXJ5QW5kRmV0Y2gBAAAAAAAAAD4WYm9laVYtZndUQlNsdDcwakFMNjU1QQ=="
}
```

Comment: i don't think so. Their documentation says it can be a string or array of strings. Besides, a string array is what Nest produces out of the scroll_id it recieves in the class constructor.

Comment: Hmmm, yes, actually it can be both a string or a list of strings... Can you run the same query in curl i.e. `curl -v -XDELETE -H 'Content-Type: application/json' localhost:9200/_search/scroll -d '{"scroll_id": ["..."]}'` and update your question with the output you get ?

Comment: I am not too familiar with curl and my authentication is a bit  peculiar  that i am not sure how to sort it out from command line with curl given my little knowledge of it. But postman apparently provides the curl version of all the api calls and here is how it looks.                                                                                                                       curl --location --request DELETE 'http:/XXXX:5050/_search/scroll' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "scroll_id": ["FGluY2x1ZGVfY29udGV4dF91dWlkDnF1ZXJ5VGkjhjkhhhhhhhhhhh"]
}'

Comment: Ok, and what does it yield if you run that command in a terminal?

Comment: Same problem here, but via Nodejs's elastic client library using `client.clearScroll()`... still not solved

Comment: Ditto for python sdk!

Comment: In fact it does work - `list` not being used in the python sense. It IS a single string of substrings, separated by commas, with each substring being a scroll_id.